# How to count the number of times a user_id is in a table?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following MySQL table:

```
user_id
-------
1
1
2
3
3
3
3
```

I would like an output of:

```
user_id  cnt
-------------
1        2
2        1
3        4
```

I though this would make that happen, but it doesn't:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(1) FROM table GROUP BY user_id
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does happen when you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY user_id;
```

btw, there is also the curiosity:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(1) FROM table GROUP BY user_id
```

Both will give you the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) as cnt FROM table GROUP BY user_id

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id, count(user_id) as total FROM temp group by user_id;
```

The query produced this.

```
user_id  total
-------------
1        2
2        1
3        4
```